# Display:inline-block usage in table - how to remove scroll bars

Tags: html, css

I want to set a span to display:inline-block, inside a td, like so:

HTML

```
<table><tr><td>

    <span class="groupName"><a href="#">small link</a></span>

    </td></tr><tr><td>

    <span class="groupName"><a href="#">really long link that should have a horizontal scroll bar</a></span>

    </td></tr></table>
```

CSS

```
td{
    /*What goes here?*/
}
.groupName{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:22px;
    max-width:300px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

This causes horizontal and vertical scroll bars on all the span or td elements. I want only horizontal scroll bars only on span elements which don't fit in the set width. Thanks for help.

**Edit** Sorry, here's a better fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/LxUht/1/

Comment: I updated my fiddle link to be more clear. I do want horizontal scroll bars if they don't fit the set width. I think the one answer works, let me check them out.

Comment: An alternative to the functionality I used this for would be to use word-wrap property, like so word-wrap:break-word;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `overflow:scroll;` to `overflow:auto` and add `white-space:nowrap` to avoid text going to next line

```
.groupName{
    display:block;
    font-size:22px;
    max-width:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UWAdehAX/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
overflow-y:hidden;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bv2ae/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have given `overflow:scroll`.

Remove `overflow:scroll` from `.groupName`

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bv2ae/1/)